# How to display the name of the page in the title bar?

Tags: master-page, page-layout, custom-masterpage

I'm a sharepoint noob so please forgive my ignorance. Basically I wanna do this:

[image]

i.e. show the name of the page selected in the drop down menu "Empowering our people" in this case on the title bar. Is there any easy way for this to be done?

One of the solutions I found online was to add this line:

```
"<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" />"
```

but i am not sure where to add it.